# Forward search in Acrobat Reader from windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, adobe-reader

In order to use my latex editor more efficiently, I'd like to know the command line syntax for forward search in Adobe Acrobat reader for windows. Haven't found any documentation on this so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
AcroRd32.exe /A "search=pdf" C:\path\to\file.pdf
```

This will search forward for the string **pdf** inside file.pdf. Ensure you have the directory of AcroRd32.exe in your PATH environment variable, or you are situated in that directory from command prompt when you run the command.